# Where to call wp_enqueue_script in a plugin with custom template?

Tags: plugin-development, templates, javascript, wp-enqueue-script

I am writing my first plugin and I have this code in the main plugin php to replace home page with custom template

```
add_filter( 'template_include', 'replace_home_page' );

function replace_home_page( $template ) {
      if (is_home()){
    return plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'mhomepagetemplate.php';
  }
  return $template;
}
```

before above code I call code to register some javascript

```
    $main_js_name='mhp_main.js';

    function load_js(){
        wp_enqueue_script($main_js_name,plugins_url($plugin_name.'/js/'.$main_js_name),array( 'jquery' ));
echo    '<BR><BR>'. plugins_url($plugin_name.'/js/'.$main_js_name);
    }

    add_action('wp_print_script','load_js');
```

the javascript file contains only one line now

```
console.log('test from js');
```

I was expecting to see the text `text from js` in javascript console but it is not there. I cannot find the code anywhere on the home page.

The custom template calls `<?php wp_head(); ?>`

Could someone help me to make the javascript work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The action is plural: [`wp_print_scripts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_print_scripts), however, the action you want to enqueue scripts on is [`wp_enqueue_scripts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts).

Comment: I don't understand what you want to say. Could you be specific what I need to do? The Codex says that it's wp_enqueue_script http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script

Comment: Did you follow the link and read the page? The *function* `wp_enqueue_script` should be used on the *action* [`wp_enqueue_scripts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts).